# replacing NULL in sqlite with value from another table via pandas merge or SQL JOIN query

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I currently have large SQLite database (~600M rows) representing mobile phone call records that look like:

```
ego_id   alter_id   date        tower_id   tower_loc
123      456        20200101    98766      California
789      143        20200105    09232      NULL
789      143        20200105    42106      NULL
```

The `NULL` values in `state` represent those tower IDs with unknown locations. It turns out that some of those `NULL` values shouldn't be `NULL`, because I have a file `towerloc.txt` (that keeps on expanding as we get new data) that looks like this:

```
tower_id     tower_loc
98766        California
09232        New York
```

which should update my table to

```
ego_id   alter_id   date        tower_id   tower_loc
123      456        20200101    98766      California
789      143        20200105    09232      New York
789      143        20200105    42106      NULL
```

If the database were small, I could do one of the following:

- load the databases into pandas, merge using `pd.merge(call_record, tower_loc_df, on='tower_id', how='left')`, and then write to a new table
- write `towerloc.txt` as a new SQL table in the same db, perform an SQL join clause via `pd.read_sql(query, engine)` and write to a new table

but these will take me **days** to do. Also, I cannot keep doing this every time `towerloc.txt` expands. So what I want is to just update the `NULL` values (and only those) by merging them with `towerloc.txt`.

What's the best and fastest way to do this, preferably without messing up with the `_ROWID_` (which I use as a fast way to count the number of rows)?

Comment: not familair with SQL Lite, but can you create views?

Comment: @Datanovice do you mean can I create a view and then update it? Apparently if a view has NULL values, I cannot update it (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/sql-views/).

Comment: yes, you could do a union of `towerloc.txt` to update the null values or something along those lines?

Comment: @Datanovice I was thinking about that too, but given that this is a large database, I was wondering how to reduce the runtime. I am also not familiar with views that much, and since there are NULL values, I don't think the view can be updated. If you could give an answer in SQL code, that would be much appreciated!

Comment: @Datanovice I tried this raw SQL: `UPDATE call_record
        SET tower_loc= (SELECT tower_loc FROM tower_loc_df WHERE tower_id = table.tower_id) WHERE (tower_loc IS NULL)` but it is very slow.